# 特定の文字列が登場するまでヒットする正規表現

Tags: java, 正規表現, kotlin

以下の「リソース」から「やりたい処理結果」のように文字列を分割する方法が分かりません。
行の先頭の`^\d+\.`を区切り文字にして文字列を分割したい感じになります。

正規表現実行環境は`Java`になります。

**リソース**

```
1.ああああああああああああ
2.いいいいいいいいいいいいい
3.うううううううううううううううう
ええええええええ6.jpgええええええ
おおおおおおおおおおおおおお
4.あああああああああ
ああああああああああああああ
あああああ6.70.ああああ
```

**やりたい処理結果**
上記テキストをこのような感じで分割したいです。
（段落ごとに複数行のテキストを分ける感じで）
段落の判定は「行の先頭が数字なおかつ、数字の次がドット」
つまり、`^\d+\.`

```
1.ああああああああああああ
```

```
2.いいいいいいいいいいいいい
```

```
3.うううううううううううううううう
ええええええええ6.jpgええええええ
おおおおおおおおおおおおおお
```

```
4.あああああああああ
ああああああああああああああ
あああああ6.70.ああああ
```

Comment: 何が問題で何を解決したいのでしょうか？

Comment: 説明難しいですが「^\d+.」〜「^\d+.」が登場する直前という正規表現を作るとマッチするのが1つ飛ばしになります。（後者のが前文、次の文の両方に該当するため）

Comment: そうしなければよく、質問文自体もそのような正規表現にはなっていないので、何が問題で何を解決したいのかがやはりわからないです。必要に応じて質問文を更新してください。あと、正規表現を実行する環境を教えてください。grepか何かでしょうか？

Comment: 正規表現はツールによって使用できるパータン等が変わってくるので、具体的なツール名を挙げてもらった方が回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 実現できているのであれば何も問題にならないのでは？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[単一行モード(`DOTALL`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)で改行も`*`にマッチするようにした上で、先読み(`(?=パターン)`)を利用すれば実現できるかと考えます。

```java
String resource = """
        1.ああああああああああああ
        2.いいいいいいいいいいいいい
        3.うううううううううううううううう
        ええええええええ6.jpgええええええ
        おおおおおおおおおおおおおお
        4.あああああああああ
        ああああああああああああああ
        あああああ6.70.ああああ
        """;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\n)(\\d+\\..*?)(?=\\n\\d+\\.|\\n$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resource);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: ありがとうございました。
そちらの正規表現で実現できました。
私の想像以上に難解な正規表現になるのですね...
「先読み」知らなかったので新しいものを知れてよかったです！